# In WebAPI2 OWIN how to combine bearer tokens and OAuth2?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I'm new to ASP.NET authentication and now playing with authentication methods. I want to implement bearer token for username/password authentication and also I want external users to login via Google and other OAuth2 providers.

I cannot achieve both methods simultaneously. I did something wrong in such a option-rich OWIN configuration.

Here is my SecurityConfig class:

```
public class SecurityConfig
{
    public static void Configure(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureTokenAuthentication(app);
        ConfigureExternalAuthentication(app);
    }

    private static void ConfigureTokenAuthentication(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        string PublicClientId = "self";
        Func<UserManager<User>> UserManagerFactory = () => new UserManager<User>(new UserStore<User>(new TicketsContext()));
        var oAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId, UserManagerFactory),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            AllowInsecureHttp = false
        };

        // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(oAuthOptions);
    }

    private static void ConfigureExternalAuthentication(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin")
        });

        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Configure Google authentication
        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = "my client id here",
            ClientSecret = "my client secret here"
        });         
    }
}
```

and here is external login method:

```
// GET api/Account/ExternalLogin
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("api/Account/ExternalLogin")]
public IHttpActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider)
{
    return new ChallengeResult(provider, "/api/home", this.Request);
}
```

When I enable both methods, just the bearer token works normally, trying to do external login answers me "error: invalid_request" and not going into controller method.

Maybe problem in this line?

```
AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
```

Trying to solve this for 2 days already.

Answer (score 0):

The OAuth2 flow implemented by UseGoogleAuthentication is not appropriate for WebApi scenarios, it relies on user interaction. Bearer tokens are the correct approach for WebApis. To get a Bearer token representing an external identity provider like Google you use an intermediary auth server like IdentityServer3. See https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3